# What is NuGet and how does it work? [Expanding on Entity Framework]

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I never fiddled with NuGet until recently that I downgraded the .NET version of my project from 4.5 to 4.0 and Visual Studio started complaining about some NuGet packages need the `EntityFramework` to be reinstalled to work again. So I went `PM> Update-Package -reinstall EntityFramework`and I was sorted.

So, now that you know how I am coming to this point, **these are my question**.

1. I am pretty sure I haven't installed NuGet on my ***Visual Studio Express 2013***. Does it come as a default feature on Visual Studio?
2. I haven't added `EntityFramework` NuGet package on my solution. Does NuGet finds out what my solution requires and it adds them automatically? In my solution I am using `EntityKey` and `EntityState` enumeration which needed `using System.Data.Entity` & `using System.Data.Entity.Core`. Visual Studio added these two namespaces when complaining about not finding those two enumerations the same way you use some LINQ and you don't have the `using System.Linq`.
3. The description for [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/ef.aspx) says *"Entity Framework is Microsoft’s recommended data access technology for new applications"*. Is this a third party library? I try not to use third party libraries as much as possible. I also found out *EntityFramework.dll* is now added to my *bin\Release* folder and I assume I will need to attach it to my executable to make it work.
4. Does NuGet do anything other than adding the required third-party *dll* to the references? I remember I used *Log4Net* in the past and I didn't use the "ease of adding packages" feature of NuGet.

Comment: We generally prefer one question per question here.

Comment: I didn't want my question to be extremely generic. However I totally agree with you @JohnSaunders. This mainly comes from, most of the articles I read about finding out what NuGet is never mentioned any details and the touched it with very broad wording.

Comment: I am going to hell for this, but ... did you even try googling all of the stuff you are asking?

Comment: I sure did @Phoenix. And the more I read about it, the less could answer my questions.

Comment: I apologize for assuming you don't know how to use google. I really thought this was one of those questions :)

Comment: @Phoenix I have earned a Business in the front, party in the back hat for this question. I assume this explains all your concerns about this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. NuGet comes with Visual Studio by default.
2. Several of the project templates (when you use New Project) include entity framework by default.
3. Depends on how you define third party.  It is a Microsoft library.  It is also a third party library if you define third party as anything you or your customer didn't write.  Entity Framework is actually now open source, but I am pretty certain the nuget package is built and published by Microsoft.
4. In addition to adding DLL references, some packages may also apply transformations such as adding default settings to config files, or adding files to your project such as code or content files.

I've never run into any big problems, but if you have a really large project I would make a backup copy of it or ensure you've checked into source control before adding a new package that you've never used before.  Usually uninstalling a package will cleanup after itself pretty well, but Nuget packages vary in quality depending on who authored them and how complex they are.